# How to migrate MFC library project from VC++6 to VC++2010 using Express Edition

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I need to migrate my MFC project done in VC++6 to VC++2010.I choose the "Create New Project from existing code files" in VC++2010.What project type I have to choose now.I am using VC++2010 express edition.Please advise if I am moving in the right direction.

Comment: projects (dsw/dsp files) of VC6 are not recognized by VS2010 platform.

Answer (score 2):

VC++ 2010 Express Edition doesn't have MFC, so you won't be able to do it, I'm afraid. You need one of the paid versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Is there any other option instead of continuing with MFC.

Comment: There are other libraries, like Qt, or other technologies, like .NET but if your project is done in MFC, you'd have to rewrite a lot or start from scratch. Without knowing more details about the project it's not easy to give advice.